# Open from command line or programatically the chrome inspector for an specific WebView of an Android App

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, command-line, webview

Having an hybrid android app, with a WebView within it, I know I can debug it with the chrome inspector. I know how to do it manually, but, can i do it automatically from a system console/terminal/bash script? or from code somehow?

1.-  So now i open the remote debugger by just putting at chrome:

`chrome://inspect/#devices`

And get this

[image]

2.-  If i click on inspect I get this:

[image]

And from the system console/terminal (not the inspector console) i'd like to open this inspection directly, so I imagine it as something like:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of what you would do from the console, to try and clarify what you're asking?

Comment: I edited the post and I think now is clearer.

Comment: Sorry but that makes no sense.  The console is part of the inspector, which is already attached to an instance for debugging.  You can't, for example, debug one website from the inspector for another website, so I don't understand why you'd expect it to be any different in this scenario.  In short, no.  Click the inspect link.

Comment: I meant from the system console/terminal (not the inspector console), sorry.

Comment: Ah okay.  In that case even more-so no, I'm afraid.  Only chrome can open the inspector as it's part of the chrome browser and it will need the browser to attach to the process you want to inspect.